# Parcel bundler "ENOENT: no such file or directory" when delete files from project

Tags: javascript, parceljs

After I've deleted couple files from project that uses Parcel bundler, command `parcel ./index.html` started to output following error:

```
Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
at Bundler.createBundleTree (<project_root>/node_modules/parcel-bundler/src/Bundler.js:654:54)
at Bundler.createBundleTree (<project_root>/node_modules/parcel-bundler/src/Bundler.js:721:12)
at Bundler.createBundleTree (<project_root>/node_modules/parcel-bundler/src/Bundler.js:721:12)
at Bundler.createBundleTree (<project_root>/node_modules/parcel-bundler/src/Bundler.js:721:12)
at Bundler.createBundleTree (<project_root>/node_modules/parcel-bundler/src/Bundler.js:721:12)
at Bundler.createBundleTree (<project_root>/node_modules/parcel-bundler/src/Bundler.js:721:12)
at Bundler.bundle (<project_root>/node_modules/parcel-bundler/src/Bundler.js:298:14)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Solution**

Delete `.parcel-cache` and `dist` folders and run command again. (NB: The cache folder was called just `.cache` in version 1.x of Parcel.)

**Proposal**

Add cleanup script for this and run it each time before parcel build:

```
 "scripts": {
   "cleanup": "rm -rf .parcel-cache dist",
   "dev": "npm run cleanup && parcel ./index.html",
   ...
 }
```

Also you can use rimraf lib to do a crossplatform cleanup task.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf. So scripts will look like this:

```
 "scripts": {
   "cleanup": "rimraf .parcel-cache dist",
   "dev": "npm run cleanup && parcel ./index.html",
   ...
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Above answer works for linux OS, if you are using windows OS rename your npm scripts as following

```
"scripts": {
"cleanup": "rmdir /q /s .parcel-cache dist",
"start": "npm run cleanup && parcel src/index.html"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on Windows:

```
"scripts": {
    "cleanup": "rmdir /q /s .parcel-cache dist || echo 'no cached files'",
    "start": "yarn run cleanup && parcel src/index.html"
}
```

The solution of "lakshan perera" did not work for me so I enhanced it.

Comment: Regarding your "_wtf?_": [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: And you could not post this code in a comment anyway. Also what you've posted is not a comment, it's an answer (which improves another one). So everything is ok, no need to mention that you can't comment yet.